How can I create the correct .htaccess file for a WordPress website?
In my WordPress website I tested these rules in the .htaccess file.
If I add the commands to redirect www to non www and redirect to https in any position other than the first and second positions, the expected redirects will be disrupted and will not work properly (I don't know why and it works correctly only in the first and second positions.
Why, if these two commands are in the second and third place, that is, after the basic commands of WordPress, does it not work properly?
Well, considering that apparently the position of commands affects the performance, is it not a problem that the basic commands of WordPress are placed in the third place (3. WordPress)?
I also used this in all three commands (because I wanted it to be separated and cleaner), but did I need to use it three times or not?
<IfModule rewrite_module>
     RewriteEngine On
     ...
     ...
     ...
</IfModule>

My htaccess file. It consists of five parts:

redirect www to non www
redirect to https
WordPress
LSCACHE
cPanel-generated handler

# BEGIN redirect www to non www
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END redirect www to non www

# BEGIN redirect to https
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END redirect to https

# BEGIN WordPress
# directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress"
# They are dynamically generated, and should only be edited by WordPress filters.
# Any changes to instructions between these pointers will be rewritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker ASYNC start ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=async_litespeed
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
### marker ASYNC end ###

### marker MOBILE start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile|Android|Silk/|Kindle|BlackBerry|Opera\ Mini|Opera\ Mobi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+ismobile]
### marker MOBILE end ###

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31557600
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31557600

ExpiresByType image/jpg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/png A31557600
ExpiresByType image/gif A31557600
ExpiresByType image/webp A31557600

ExpiresByType video/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31557600
ExpiresByType video/webm A31557600

ExpiresByType text/css A31557600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31557600

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31557600
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31557600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/otf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A31557600

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


Reason why the order of directives is important: simply because directives are executed from top to bottom. Which is why implementing external redirections before internal rewritings does make a lot of sense.

So the current order of my commands is correct as it is now and does not need to be changed? Isn't it a problem that the WordPress commands are in the third place and the redirect commands are first? Does this not create a problem for WordPress commands?

I'd say you don need the <IfModule rewrite_module> constructs at all . Why? What for? What advantage does it offer? Your site does not work if you don't have that module loaded anyway. It does not matter why it does not work then. Which is why I consider using those constructs in private, individual setups obsolete and annoying, they only make the implementation harder to read. Things are different if you implement a library or framework that is to be deployed to setups unknown to you.

Why should it be an issue if the internal wordpress directives rewrites come after the external redirections? That is perfectly fine and actually required.

thanks. So I can also remove this <IfModule rewrite_module> and this RewriteEngine On from all my commands?

You do need the RewriteEngine OnBut I, personally, prefer implementations without those conditionals testing whether the rewriting module has been loaded. If not your site does not work anyway. It does not matter if it breaks due to a syntax error or due to a missing rewriting setup then. Those tests only make sense if you provide an alternate mechanism if the module is not loaded. Which you don't do. So what is the point in testing?

Question: are you aware about the difference between an external redirection and an internal rewrite at all?

yes i know this

Then you should easily understand why external redirections need to get applied first ...

I'd combine the force HTTPS and non-WWW, and switch the WordPress rewrite section just before the handler.
# BEGIN redirect www to non www and Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
# END redirect www to non www and Force HTTPS


# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker ASYNC start ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=async_litespeed
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
### marker ASYNC end ###

### marker MOBILE start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile|Android|Silk/|Kindle|BlackBerry|Opera\ Mini|Opera\ Mobi [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+ismobile]
### marker MOBILE end ###

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker WEBP start ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "image/webp"
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone.*Version/(\d{2}).*Safari
RewriteCond %1 >13
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{ENV:LSCACHE_VARY_VALUE}+webp]
### marker WEBP end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31557600
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31557600

ExpiresByType image/jpg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/png A31557600
ExpiresByType image/gif A31557600
ExpiresByType image/webp A31557600

ExpiresByType video/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31557600
ExpiresByType video/webm A31557600

ExpiresByType text/css A31557600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31557600

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31557600
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31557600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/otf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A31557600

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress"
# They are dynamically generated, and should only be edited by WordPress filters.
# Any changes to instructions between these pointers will be rewritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Feel free to give it a try, it should work, if not, please leave a comment.

I apologize for all the delays. it works great. can I use an address to automatically detect the site domain address instead of my domain? I mean dynamically get an address maybe like  {THE_REQUEST}

Yes, feel free to replace it with "%{SERVER_NAME}"

Now i replaced RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain/$1 [R=301,L] line to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301,L] it's ok?

Should be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
